# Выровнять содержимое блоков в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Приветствую, имеется сайт http://paynplay.pro.

Скриншот проблемы:[image: Скриншот проблемы]

Необходимо выровнять высоту "h2" с названием товара и "p" с описанием товара (не зависимо от количества символов в данных тегах), а так же прижать кнопку с ценой к низу блока (все они одинаковы по высоте).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0051)http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ -->
<html lang="en" class="mdl-js">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

  <title>Pay'n'Play - Главная</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?145"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand">Pay'n'Play</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./topsales">Популярное</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">В разработке</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Поиск">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Поиск</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="first-slide" src="https://paynplay.pro/images/ghostrecon.jpg" alt="Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
            <h1 style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px 1px 0 #000;">Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h1>
            <p style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px 1px 0 #000;">Создайте и настройте своего "Призрака", его оружие и снаряжение.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">1999 р.</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="https://paynplay.pro/images/gtav.jpg" alt="Grand Theft Auto V">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
            <h1 style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px 1px 0 #000;">Grand Theft Auto V</h1>
            <p style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px 1px 0 #000;">Не просто игра – это легенда!</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">1199 р.</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="https://paynplay.pro/images/dow3.jpg" alt="Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
            <h1 style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px 1px 0 #000;">Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h1>
            <p style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px 1px 0 #000;">Вступите в жестокую битву между тремя враждующими фракциями в игре Dawn of War III.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">1799 р.</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
          </div>
          <!--/span-->
        </div>
        <!--/row-->
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item disabled">
              <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Назад</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">Вперед</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!--/span-->
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between active">
            Категории
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info justify-content-between">
            <a href="">Steam</a>
            <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">70</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between">
            <a href="">Steam ключи</a>
            <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">13</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between">
            <a href="">Steam гифты</a>
            <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">34</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between">
            <a href="">Steam аккаунты</a>
            <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">23</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info justify-content-between">
            <a href="">Origin</a>
            <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">21</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between">
            <a href="">Origin ключи</a>
            <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">10</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between">
            <a href="">Origin аккаунты</a>
            <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">11</span>
          </li>
        </ul><br>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between active">
            Реквизиты
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" style="text-align:center;">
            <div style="display:block; margin:0 auto;">
              Webmoney<br> Персональный аттестат<br>
              <img src="https://paynplay.pro/images/att.png" alt="Персональный аттестат"><br> WMID: <a href="https://passport.webmoney.ru/asp/certview.asp?wmid=343197855963" target="_blank">343197855963</a><br><br>
              <img src="https://paynplay.pro/images/yad.png" alt="Яндекс Деньги"><br> Пройдена идентификация<br> Номер кошелька: 410011363247780
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer>
      <p class="float-right"><a href="" onclick="return up()">Вернуться на верх</a></p>
      <p>© 2017 Pay'n'Play.PRO · <a href="/">Политика</a> · <a href="/">Соглашение</a></p>
    </footer>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
  <!-- VK Widget -->
  <!-- VK Widget -->
  <div id="vk_community_messages"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 146199849, {
      expandTimeout: "10000",
      tooltipButtonText: "Остались вопросы?"
    });
  </script>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://paynplay.pro/js/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://paynplay.pro/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://paynplay.pro/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
  <script src="https://paynplay.pro/js/holder.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var t;

    function up() {
      var top = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop, document.documentElement.scrollTop);
      if (top > 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0, -100);
        t = setTimeout('up()', 20);
      } else clearTimeout(t);
      return false;
    }
  </script>




  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: -100%; left: -100%;"><defs><style type="text/css"></style></defs><text x="0" y="25" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:25pt;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Open Sans, sans-serif">500x500</text></svg></body>

</html>
```

Кусок кода с проблемой:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Custom styles for this template --><link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <!--/span-->
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами в отладке должны содержать код прямо в вопросе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Crantisz, вроде бы исправил, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз используете bootstrap4 с флексами, сделайте это теми же флексами. Если будете использовать этот ответ не забудьте добавить вендорные префиксы.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item-header {
  flex-basis: 120px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <!--/span-->
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь с кнопками. Можно ли как-то выровнять описание? https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/05/afaa796b13f7da51f702fed91e2b5da8.png - скриншот проблемы, которая осталась. :)

Comment: @Luzik, вы хотите что бы они были на одном уровне, относительно друг друга?

Comment: да, хотелось бы, чтоб названия, описания и кнопки были на одном уровне относительно друг друга в одном ряду. :)

Comment: @Luzik, можно сделать что бы заголовки были как сейчас, а текст был на одном уровне ниже, можно добавить заголовкам флекс родителей и выровнять их по центру) как сделать?

Comment: @Luzik, добавил вариант, где заголовки вертикально по центру, как по мне он симпатичнее

Comment: в css/html я туп, к сожалению. (https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/05/ca793536f6e647fffe83e02bd5a16c78.png) Видимо, я что-то не так делаю. :(

Comment: @Luzik я добавил в пример код, попробуй его

Answer (score 0):

Код, который действительно помог мне выровнять содержимое блоков. Огромное спасибо @nueq за помощь!

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item-header {
  flex-basis: 120px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="https://paynplay.pro/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon® Wildlands</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1999р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1199р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h2>Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">1799р.</a></p>
  </div>
  <!--/span-->
</div>
```